# Change my list comprehension into a better one

Tags: python, list

I want to flatten the following list to a new list:

```py
countries = [[('Finland', 'Helsinki')], [('Sweden', 'Stockholm')], [('Norway', 'Oslo')]]
```

output:

```py
['FINLAND', 'HELSINKI', 'SWEDEN', 'STOCKHOLM', 'NORWAY', 'OSLO']
```

My solution, but I think it is too long and I can do it easier:

```py
x=[i for j in countries for i in j]
y=[i for j in x for i in j]
print(y)
```

Comment: Hello! You may want to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165). Can you elaborate on what you consider "easier" and "better"?

Comment: @user10451243 would you mind marking my answer as the correct one (click the checkmark) if it the correct answer??

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
a = [y for i in countries for x in i for y in x]
```

The for i in countries, loops through [[('Finland', 'Helsinki')], [('Sweden', 'Stockholm')], [('Norway', 'Oslo')]], the for i in x loops through the list, [('Finland', 'Helsinki')], and the for y in x, loops through the tuples, ('Finland', 'Helsinki').

If you want to capitalize all the country names, do this:

```
a = [y.upper() for i in countries for x in i for y in x]
```

Comment: would you mind marking my answer as the correct one (click the checkmark) if it the correct answer??